# How to automatically compress files in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am totally new to Hadoop, and I want to compress a big file and place it in HDFS.So far this is what I have done 
1) Installed single node cluster 
2) My core-site.xml is like

```
<configuration>
<property> <name>fs.defaultFS</name> 
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
</property> 
<property> <name>io.compression.codecs</name>  
<value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Now when I am coping a local 2GB file into HDFS , using following command.I still see same size in HDFS.

```
hadoop fs -put 06_27_06_2016_tcp-leef.log-online /user/hduser/test/
```

Not sure what I am missing here ,is there any other property which I need to enable in Hadoop environment or Do i need to write map-reduce program for this?So the requirement is whenever a new file comes in HDFS it should automatically compressed .

Thanks
VG

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write map-reduce job to compress your data in hdfs. I don't know if there is a way to do automatic compress on hadoop put operation, but suppose it does not exist. One option is to put already compressed file:

```
gzip 06_27_06_2016_tcp-leef.log-online
hdfs dfs -put 06_27_06_2016_tcp-leef.log-online.gz /user/hduser/test/
```

Another way is to compress it inside mapreduce job. 
As an option you can use hadoop streaming jar for compressing you files within hdfs:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar \
-Dmapred.output.compress=true \
-Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
-Dmapred.output.compression.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec \
-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
-input <input-path> \
-output $OUTPUT \
```

There is a nice article about data compression in hadoop, hope you'll find it quite helpful:

http://comphadoop.weebly.com/

Comment: Thank you Alex make sense to me , but can please give me some more clarity on why we need or the purpose of compress property in core-site.xml, or maperd-site.xml files?

Comment: @user3332404 example I've provided is to apply compression for  single time map-reduce job output data Setting this property in mapred-site.xml will apply it for all your map-reduce jobs output data automatically, so that you wouldn't have to set this parameter each time you running a job